I'm trying to calculate the cumulative percentage
I'll start by saying that I'm at level 0 with the SQL language;
I created this query to group the number of invoices processed after 0,1,2,… days from receipt [field T_Elab(gg)].



T_Elab(gg)
Num_Fat
TOTALE
%




0
100
331
30.21


1
112
331
33.84


2
38
331
11.48


3
39
331
8.16


4
27
331
2.42


5
8
331
0.30


6
1
331
0.30


8
1
331
0.30


9
1
331
0.30


10
1
331
0.30


11
1
331
0.30


12
1
331
0.30


14
1
331
0.30



The TOTAL column shows the number of invoices recorded in the month (in the example it's May), the % column calculates the percentage compared to the total.
This is the query:
select  datediff(q.datareg,f.dataricezione) as 'T_Elab(gg)' ,  
count(datediff(q.datareg,f.dataricezione)) as 'Num_Fat' ,  
(count(datediff(q.datareg,f.dataricezione)) / 
(select count(*) /100 from cfatacq q2   where   q2.annoreg>=2024  and   q2.datareg>='2024-05-01'    and q2.datareg<='2024-05-31'     and  datediff(q2.datareg,f.dataricezione)<30 ) ) as'%'  ,
(select count(*)  from cfatacq q2 where q2.annoreg>=2024  and q2.datareg>='2024-05-01'  and q2.datareg<='2024-05-31'  and  datediff(q2.datareg,f.dataricezione)<30)  as 'TOTALE
from cfatacq q      
left join lsfaecoda f on (q.idprog=f.idprogfattura)      
where   q.annoreg>=2024  and q.datareg>='2024-05-01'  and q.datareg<='2024-05-31'  and  datediff(q.datareg,f.dataricezione)<30   group by datediff(q.datareg,f.dataricezione)

I would like to add the cumulative percentage, like this



T_Elab(gg)
Num_Fat
TOTALE
%
% cumulative




0
100
331
30.21
30.21


1
112
331
33.84
64.05


2
38
331
11.48
75.53


3
39
331
11.78
87.31


4
27
331
8.16
95.47


5
8
331
2.42
97.89


6
1
331
0.30
98.19


8
1
331
0.30
98.49


9
1
331
0.30
98.79


10
1
331
0.30
99.09


11
1
331
0.30
99.40


12
1
331
0.30
99.70


14
1
331
0.30
100.00



but I don't know which commands to use.
Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Look at "window" functions
